# Reusing Reducer Logic does not toggle object using Redux and React'

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am reusing the same reducer logic for two different events. The idea is to toggle a class depending on which text you clicked on. Each event fires, but my object is not toggling. Any thoughts?

App:

```js
import React from "react"
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import * as toggleactionCreators from '../actions/toggleActions';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    hiddenA: state.toggleA.hidden,
    hiddenB: state.toggleB.hidden
  }
}

function mapDispachToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({...toggleactionCreators}, dispatch)
}

class Main extends React.Component {

  toggleDiv() {
    this.props.toggleDiv();
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  render() {
    const { hiddenA, hiddenB } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      <div>
        <h3 onClick={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)} className={ hiddenA ? null : "toggled"} >Good Day!</h3>
        <h1 onClick={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)} className={ hiddenB ? null : "toggled"} >Hello There!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    )    
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(Main);
```

Index Reducer:

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import toggle from "./toggleReducer"

function createNamedWrapperReducer(reducerFunction, reducerName) {
  return (state, action) => {
      const {name} = action;
      const isInitializationCall = state === undefined;
      if(name !== reducerName && !isInitializationCall) return state;
      return reducerFunction(state, action);    
  }
}
const thereducer = combineReducers({
    toggleA : createNamedWrapperReducer(toggle, 'A'),
    toggleB : createNamedWrapperReducer(toggle, 'B'),
});

export default thereducer;
```

toggleReducer:

```js
const toggle = (state = { hidden: true}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
      return Object.assign({}, ...state, {hidden: !state.hidden});
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default toggle;
```

toggleAction:

```js
export const toggleDiv = () => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_DIV',
  }
}
```

Comment: Your action don't seem to have a `name` attribute. Maybe take that as an argument in your action creator?

Comment: What am I passing in?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would debug this.

1. Download Redux DevTools for your browser. This is the URL for chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd
2. Download React devtools for you browser. This is the URL for chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi
3. Look in Redux Devtools:

   - Is the action emitted from your action creator
   - Does the reducer update the state correctly?
4. If both the actions, and reducers looks correctly, check your React component:

   - Does the component receive the correct props? If yes, it's something with how the props are rendered. If no, it's something with how the store is connected to your component.

Hope this debugging tutorial is useful for you. If you have any follow up questions, please don't hesitate to ask :)